# Firebase realtime database - Get all child that contain given key in subchild

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have my realtime database structured like this

-(key: **rides**, value: **null**)
--(key: **someRideId**, value: **null**)
---(key: **driver**, value: **someDriverId**)
---(key: **passengers**, value:**null**)
-----(key:**somePassengerId1**, value: **null**)
-----(key:**somePassengerId2**, value: **null**)

I have many rides, I want to make a query to find all the rides that contains a given passengerId in their passengers child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database queries work on a flat list of nodes, and order/filter on data at a fixed path under each child node in that list. Your structure has two repeated levels, so does need those criteria.

What you **can** do on your current data structure is to:

- Find all rides for a specific driver
- Within one known ride, look for a specific passenger

But you can't look across all rides for a passenger.

---

For that use-case you'll most likely want to created an **additional** inverted list where you first have the passenger ID as a key, and then all their ride IDs under that.

So looking up the ride info for a passenger then becomes a two-step process:

1. Load the ride IDs for that passenger from `/passengerRides/$passengerID`
2. Load the data for each ride (if needed)

Step 2 is not nearly as slow as you may think, as the Firebase SDK [pipelines all those requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786) over a single connection efficiently.

---

Also see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)